# Python Subplots Automate nrows and ncolumns

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am writing code that will output subplots for anything between 1 subplot and 20 subplots. The row and column configuration for all 20 different types of plots will be different, (e.g. for 4 subplots, I'll want 2 rows and 2 columns, but for 12 subplots I'll want 3 rows and 4 columns), and instead of typing in the number of rows and columns I want for each different number of subplots, I was wondering if there was a way to automatically generate the nrow and ncolumn values based off of the number of subplots I want in the image. I know there are similar questions to this out there, but I've only seen answers that suggest manually entering in the number of rows and columns you want for each subplot, and haven't seen a way to automate it yet. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the package grid_strategy? https://github.com/matplotlib/grid-strategy